# Create new file - Getting IOException

Tags: java, file, io

I'm trying to create a settings file for my program, but when I debug the program, I get an IOException.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
// Universal Android Toolkit
String docs = new String(System.getProperty("user.home"));
String uatDocs = docs + "/Team_M4gkBeatz/Universal_Android_Toolkit";
// Settings
File sets = new File(uatDocs + "/Settings/Settings_uat.uatsavefile");

private void createSettings()
{
    try
    {
        jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
        progress += "Creating settings file... ";
        jTextArea2.setText(progress);
        sets.createNewFile();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        progress += "Done.\nLoading UI...\n";
        jTextArea2.setText(progress);
        jProgressBar1.setValue(100);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: There was an error while creating the settings file.\n" + ex + "\nPlease report this error to the developer/s.\nThe application will now close.", "Error Creating Settings File", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the file is on the path you think it is? Print it out and verify.

Comment: What does the stacktrace say?

Comment: Post the exception you are getting (including complete stack trace).

Comment: I'm 100% positive it is. Look here: https://db.tt/bgeJoIxa

Comment: The error is: java.io.IOException: The system could not find the path specified.

Comment: A wild guess: ensure that the parent directory is existing. Use something like the following: `sets.getParentFile().mkdirs()`.

Comment: @ortang Thanks. Worked like a charm. I thought it would create the directory for me.

Comment: @Beatsleigher, good to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't upper folder

```
System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Team_M4gkBeatz/Universal_Android_Toolkit/Settings"
```

so you cann't create the file. So you should check it and create folders:

```
final File parentDirectory = sets.getParentFile();
if (!parentDirectory.exists()) // checks that directory exists
{
   parentDirectory.mkdirs();   
}
if (!sets.exists()) // checks that file exists
{
   sets.createNewFile();
}
```